# Dendrogram Clustering Height Determination - R

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

In R, I have got the Cluster Dendrogram plotted with y axis values- 0 -4.

- How can i determine the exact heights of different clusters? Some of them are in between two numbers.
- Also, I want to automatically separate the data groups clustered in the graph. I came across cutree function but I have to pass explicitly the value of k,h to it. Is it possible to perform the separation without passing values manually?

Comment: have you had a look to `?dendrogram` and `?as.dendrogram` ? particularly the Details section? What do you mean by "without passing values manually" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the heights for different cuts you can use the [dendextend](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/index.html) package, with the `heights_per_k.dendrogram` function. For example:

```
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests[1:4,]), "ave")
dend <- as.dendrogram(hc)
heights_per_k.dendrogram(dend)
##       1        2        3        4 
##86.47086 68.84745 45.98871 28.36531
```

As to your second question: if you don't tell cutree how many clusters you want, it won't know how many to give you.